# Как получить доступ к файлам и папкам Windows из Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, файловая-система, dual-boot

У меня установлены две системы на одном компе (dual boot) Windows 10 и Linux Ubuntu 16.04
На Windows находится нужная для работы информация. Как получить к ней доступ?

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Windows была выключена как положено, без гибернации.
Какой самый правильный способ получения доступа к файловой системе Windows из Linux?

UPD. Удалил гибернацию из Windows с помощью `powercfg -h off` и проблема исчезла.

Comment: А вы уверены что без гибернации? А то слыхал я что 10-ка всегда так выключается и отдельно настраивать нормальное выключение надо...

Comment: Действительно, хоть я и вышел из винды без гибернации, она всё-равно как-то запустила гибернацию, потому что когда я опять зашел и удалил гибернацию вовсе, с помощью команды powercfg -h off проблема исчезла и теперь я могу открывать папки в виндовс из-под линукса. Так что спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 2):

1. В поле поиска введите Электропитание и нажмите Ввод.
2. Выбор, выберите действия кнопок питания.
3. Щелкните изменение параметров, которые сейчас недоступны.
4. Прокрутите вниз параметры завершения работы и снимите флажок
   Включить быстрый запуск
5. Нажмите кнопку сохранить изменения.